# NoReverseMatch at... (Django)

Tags: python, django

Getting error:

> Reverse for 'topping' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topping/(?P<toppings_id>[0-9]+)/$']
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/pizzas/
> Django Version: 3.2.8
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
> Exception Value:
> Reverse for 'topping' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topping/(?P<toppings_id>[0-9]+)/$']

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Pizzas, Toppings

admin.site.register(Pizzas)
admin.site.register(Toppings)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Pizzas(models.Model):
    """A Pizza for the menu."""
    pizza = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        """Return string of model."""
        return self.pizza

class Toppings(models.Model):
    """A topping for each pizza."""
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizzas, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topping = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'toppings'

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.topping}"
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

from .models import Pizzas

```
def index(request):
    """The home page for pizzeria."""
    return render(request, 'pizzas/index.html')


def pizzas(request):
    """Show all pizzas."""
    pizzas = Pizzas.objects.all()
    context = {'pizzas': pizzas}
    return render(request, 'pizzas/pizzas.html', context)


def topping(request, toppings_id):
    """Show each topping for a pizza."""
    pizzas = Pizzas.objects.get(id=toppings_id)
    toppings = pizzas.topping_set.all()
    context = {'pizzas': pizzas, 'toppings': toppings}
    return render(request, 'pizzas/toppings.html', context)
```

project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pizzas.urls')),
]
```

app urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
```

from . import views

app_name = 'pizzas'

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # Pizza menu
    path('pizzas/', views.pizzas, name='pizzas'),
    # Detail page for Toppings.
    path('pizzas/<int:toppings_id>/', views.topping, name='topping'),
]
```

pizzas.html template:

```html
{% extends "pizzas/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Pizzas</p>

  <ul>
      {% for pizza in pizzas %}
        <li>
          <a href="{% url 'pizzas:topping' toppings.id %}">{{ pizza }}</a>{{ pizza }}
        </li>
      {% empty %}
        <li>No pizzas.</li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

I've included what I assume is important. Beginner programmer here, so if there's anything I've left out of this post let me know. I tried my best to read up on what the cause of a NoReverseMatch are, but none of the solutions fixed the issue. The pizzas function is getting all the pizzas and related toppings and storing in a database which assigns the toppings an id? which should then be acquired through the get()? is how I am understanding this.

Comment: You don't have `toppings` in the context of the `pizzas` view, you use `toppings.id` in the url tag in the `pizzas.html` template, when something is not found in the context an empty string is returned so you pass an empty string to the url

Comment: I think it is because of the named argument for the url.
Have you tried {% url 'pizzas:topping' toppings_id=toppings.id %}

Comment: @IainShelvington, I added toppings to the context but got a type error instead.

Comment: I agree with @IainShelvington, it looks like `toppings` is not set in `pizzas view`. How did you add it to have a type error?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your model looks like, but if toppings is a field under the Pizza model (it'd only make sense if it was) you have to access it the same way you would any field on a model:

```
pizza.toppings.id
```

Comment: The models.py is pasted above. but no, toppings isn't part of the topping model, toppings is its own model.